# Por que .dat e não .txt?

Tags: c, arquivo, extensão

Estou realizando um trabalho para a minha faculdade na linguagem C, seria basicamente o sistema inteiro de uma sapataria, com manipulação de arquivos. Procurando alguns exemplos de `CRUD` na internet eu encontrei vários que fazem uso de arquivos `.dat`, e nenhum que faz uso de um `.txt`.

O `.Dat` é melhor para manipular os arquivos? Por que não `txt` (tudo que me ensinaram até agora foi apenas em `txt`)?

Teria algum jeito de eu melhor visualizar o que está escrito em um arquivo `.dat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dat` é só um nome qualquer, isso indica nada sobre o que ele tem dentro, não existe sequer especificação que diz que um `.dat` deve ser de um jeito ou de outro, assim como um `.txt também não, embora costuma-se usar um texto sem formatação alguma.

Costumam usar isso para dizer que tem dados lá dentro, nada mais que isto, cada uso pode ser de um jeito. Obviamente que é mais comum algo que tenha dados binários (codificados assim, aceitando a faixa inteira de um byte e não apenas um subconjunto, porque tecnicamente só texto também não deixa de ter uma forma binária) enquanto que um `.txt` espera-se que tenha só textos simples.

Para você visualizar apenas pode abrir em qualquer editor, alguns vão mostrar dados binários melhor que outros, mas eles serão essencialmente ilegíveis. Alguns editores foram feitos para ler binários e possuem ferramentas específicas para isto.

Fora isto você pode criar um código que abra e leia todos os dados de forma livre, ou seja, byte por byte sem se importar com o conteúdo.